# Jetbrains 0XDBE - Trying to connect to SQL Server, Getting errors with sqljdbc_auth

Tags: sql-server, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I have installed Jetbrains new Database IDE - 0XDBE.
I having trouble connecting with sql server DB. 
I have already downloaded sqljdbc_4.0 driver and specified the location of this driver.
But when i try to connect as trusted connection,  I am getting following error. 
"java.sql.SQLException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication."
To fix that i have to put sqljdbc_auth.dll to a particular location.
I have tried many location but unable to locate the right one and keep getting the same error.

Do I need to install whole java to make it run?

Answer (score 6):

I got this error when trying to connect to SQL server using integrated security.

Download the .tar.gz version of the JDBC driver for SQL Server from Microsoft: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774

1. Open the archive (using 7zip or something similar) and find x86
   version of the file `sqljdbc_auth.dll` (It should be in
   `sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86\`)
2. Extract `sqljdbc_auth.dll` to the 0xDBE java runtime binary folder.
   On my machine this is located at: `C:\Program Files
   (x86)\JetBrains\0xDBE 138.551\jre\jre\bin`
3. Make sure you have integrated security enabled in the driver options
   for your connection and then it should work correctly.

---

You can find more info in this thread on the JetBrains forum: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/455251

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing Java in my machine. Could not find another way yet.